# Align borders of text div with image div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I have the following code using bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="test1" style="text-align:center; border-style:double; font-size:14px" class="col-lg-6">
                JVM Infotech is a multifunctional company that can serve many of your educational needs.
            </div>
            <div id="test2" style=" border-style:double" class="col-lg-6" >
                <img  style="margin:auto" src="cinq1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The size of div test1 is based on the amount of text and fontsize of test1. So the bottom border does not automatically align with div test2. I am able to fix this by changing padding values of test1. But that means each change of text to test1 will require change of padding values as well which is not good stable coding. I thought the grid system of Bootstrap 3 would adjust for this so is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Could you provide some working code on e.g. http://jsbin.com?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without javascript you can achieve it--
It's a bootstrap experiment--[the official experiment](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13203)

you just need to add `.row-eq-height` with row class.
and add the following css.

```css
 .row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
       </head>
       <body>
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="row row-eq-height" >
            <div id="test1" style="text-align:center; border-style:double; font-size:14px;" class="col-lg-6 ">
                JVM Infotech is a multifunctional company that can serve many of your educational needs.
            </div>
            <div id="test2" style=" border-style:double; " class="col-lg-6 " >
                <img  style="margin:auto" src="cinq1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: it uses flex.

Comment: The OP is using Bootstrap 3 which doesn't support Flexbox by default. I realise it can be done this way, but Using Bootstrap 3 the jQuery solution is likely easier.

Comment: I understand that I am just providing another way. The op might find it helpful.

Comment: Sure, no problem, and I didn't know myself about row-eq-height :)

Comment: i dont have to use bootstrap 3. I can use 4. While this doesnt answer my specific question, it let me know what I need to do to fix it. I would have thought something as simple as vertical align of cols would have been considered in bootstrap 3. Also i dont know anything about flex. to use it do i just create a class def in css with the display values?

Comment: If you use bootstrap 4 the columns are automatically gets equal height ..flexbox is incorporated inside B4 natively..for bootstrap 3 you just need to copy the css from my answer  and use row-eq-height as class with the row div that will do..in both the cases you don't need to know flexbox

Comment: oh ok. im still new to css. not sure what the webkit values  are doing. will dig deeper on the net. thanks.

Comment: what version are you using? if B3 this code is compatible with it you don't need to change the link..actually this is the only solution vailable for B3..weird that i got downvoted! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no default way in Bootstrap 3 (There will be in 4) to make to columns of dynamic data equal height... but you could use jQuery. Here I made your two columns "sm" so they show up side by side here in the snippet, and changed the broken image to some short text:

```js
$(function() {
  var leftHeight = $('#test1').height();
  var rightHeight = $('#test2').height();

  if (leftHeight > rightHeight) {
    $('#test2').height(leftHeight);
  } else {
    $('#test1').height(rightHeight);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="test1" style="text-align:center; border-style:double; font-size:14px" class="col-sm-6">
        JVM Infotech is a multifunctional company that can serve many of your educational needs.
      </div>
      <div id="test2" style=" border-style:double" class="col-sm-6">
        Less text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works to align the div heights but then the text is no longer vertically centered. And if I use padding the script stops workings. How do I edit the code snippet? Needed to change it for it to work.....